# Diference betwen Exception Handling and Async Exception handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, exception

I have created a Web API app and don't understand how my Global Exception Handling works. The following code doesn't work:

```
public void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context){
    if (context.Exception is ObjectNotFoundException)
    {
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(context.Exception.Message),
            ReasonPhrase = "Nothing here for you"
        };

        context.Result = new ObjectNotFoundException(context.Request, result);
    }
}
```

But this works fine:

```
 public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context){
    if (context.Exception is ObjectNotFoundException)
    {
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(context.Exception.Message),
            ReasonPhrase = "Nothing here for you"
        };

        context.Result = new ObjectNotFoundException(context.Request, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error why first doesn't work?

Comment: @DhavalR No, first just don't handler exception.

Comment: reason is the 'override' keyword being required, due to implementing the base class.. details below in the answer

Answer (score 3):

In you code, the only difference is the *override* keyword. Hence that's the source of problem here.

Since the method *Handles* requires to be overridden from the base abstract class ExceptionHandler, you need to use the override keyword.

Without override, you are creating a new implementation and removing the base implementation out there. Hence the method invocation gets removed from pipeline and is equivalent to no such method being present out there.

if you want to do async handling, you need to use "HandleAsync" method instead of "Handle"..    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.exceptionhandling.exceptionhandler.handleasync(v=vs.118).aspx

Any async handler will be just enable non-blocking execution. Hence if your logging/handling takes quite long, or there's an expected load out there due to too many requests in pipeline, use async.

Comment: Are you *sure* that the async handler is actually running on another thread?  Remember that `async` alone does not imply multi-threading.

Comment: @BradleyUffner corrected the response. Agree (async === multithreading) = false   (noting the === vs ==)